# How to test Vue3 and intertia with jest

Tags: laravel, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, inertiajs

In a `Laravel` + `Vue3` + `Inertia` project which setup using `Laravel Mix`, how we can create **front-end** tests?

Especially, I have no idea how to handle `Inertia`'s `Share Data`, `usePage()` and `useForm` methods?

The first error I'm facing is:

```sh
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'someSharedData')                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                              
      2 |                                                                                                                                                     
      3 | export const handleSometing = (something) =>                                                                                                        
    > 4 |   usePage().props.value.someSharedData                                                                                                
        |   ^                                                                                                                                                 
      5 |     ...                                                                                                              
      6 |   )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After googling some useless hours and finding nothing to this exact problem, I've found this solution.

The key was in `Jest Partial Mocking`!
You can mock `useForm`, `usePage`, and then `Shared Data` using `Jest Partial Mocking`.
After setup the `vue-test-util`, I have created this test file and it was working like a charm.

In the below example, the `i18n` is mocked using the `config` object of the `vue-test-utils`.
The `Inertia`'s methods are mocked by `jest.mock()`.

```js
import { config, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Dashboard from '@/Components/ExampleComponent'

config.global.mocks = {
  $t: () => '',
}

jest.mock('@inertiajs/inertia-vue3', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual('@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'), // Keep the rest of Inertia untouched!
  useForm: () => ({
    /** Return what you need **/
    /** Don't forget to mock post, put, ... methods **/
  }),
  usePage: () => ({
    props: {
      value: {
        someSharedData: 'something',
      },
    },
  }),
}))

test('Render ExampleComponent without crash', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(ExampleComponent, {
    props: {
      otherPageProps: {}
    }
  })

  expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('Hi! I am ExampleComponent.')
})
```

Comment: Hi, how does one mock post, put, etc inside useForm... also with an object?